# beginSheetModalForWindow method error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I can't understand why beginSheetModalForWindow is not working.

Here is the content of MyAppDelegate.h

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

MyAppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

}

@end
```

In my AppController.m I have these lines of code

```
NSAlert *alert = [[[NSAlert alloc] init] autorelease];
        [alert setMessageText:@"Alert."];

        [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:window
                          modalDelegate:self
                         didEndSelector:@selector(alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                            contextInfo:nil];
```

The problem is that I get an error: Use of undeclared identifier window.

What I miss ?

Comment: Please check what you have declared window in AppController.h file. I suspect the problem is in your .h file only

Answer (score 0):

'window' is a variable belonging to your MyAppDelegate instance. In order to make use of the same window variable inside of AppController, AppController needs a reference to the window. I'm not sure what the relationship between these two classes is, but generally when one class needs to provide another class with a reference to one of its instance variables, the reference is passed in a method call. For instance, you might add a setWindow: method to the AppController, and have the MyAppDelegate call that method, providing the variable 'window'